# Event handling on dynamic canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

... an array of canvas elements.
I dont really understand the (e) argument, and how to pass which canvas was clicked to the move function.
This simple demo draws canvas elements, and I want the one that is clicked to move down.
do I need to use .this as the e ???

```
<script>
var n=0, canv=[], ct=[]
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var t=0
for (n=0; n<10; n++){ // create 10 canvas
 canv[n] = document.createElement('canvas');
 canv[n].id = "C"+n;
 canv[n].width = rnd(300);
 canv[n].height = rnd(300);
 canv[n].style.zIndex = n;
 canv[n].style.position = "absolute";
 canv[n].style.border = "2px solid";

body.appendChild(canv[n]);
ct[n] = canv[n].getContext("2d");

canv[n].addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    move(n)
});

}

function move(num){
 t++
 canv[num].style.top=t
}

function rnd(m){return Math.floor(Math.random()*m)}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: e.currentTarget is the canvas object.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
I see .this in some code which I thought refers to the current object, but is .this not really something I would use here?

Comment: In this instance `this` and `e.currentTarget` would be the same thing, however event bubbling means that sometimes the thing handling the event is not the same as the thing rasing the event